# How many variances of a working day in a week

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Go easy on me please, have been scratching my head and googling all day to try and figure out the solution to this.
If I have employees that can work $1$ or $2$ or $3$ or $4$ or $5$ days a week, how many variances of working day patterns are there?
So for $1$ day a week worker, there are $7$ variances (they can work mon/tues/wed/thurs/etc...)
for $2$ day a week worker, there are $21$ variances (I think) I've worked out long hand.
How many for each type of worker? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

You could think as follows

For the $1$ day case you have a *bowl* called *the work day* and you would like to count the different possibilities to fill it, and you are right it is $7$ different possibilities.
You could also think as how many ways to pick one object out of $7$ objects which is usually denoted and evaluated as follows
$$
C_n^{k}=\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!\cdot(n-k)!}
$$
So in this particular case
$$
C_7^{1}=\binom{7}{1}=\frac{7!}{1!\cdot6!}=7.
$$

For the two day variation you may think of it as $2$ bowls which are to be filled with one day each, for the first bowl you could choose out of $7$ different days, and for the second bowl you have $6$ different days left to choose from. For each of the $7$ choices for the first bowl you will have $6$ choices for the second one which gives $7\cdot 6=42$ and we have to divide by $2!$ since we can arrange the bowls in $2$ different ways (you could think of this as we gave an order to the bowls *first* and *second* which was not needed).

Or you could go and use the formula giving

$$
C_7^{2}=\binom{7}{2}=\frac{7!}{2!\cdot(5)!}=21.
$$

I hope this helped

Comment: Fab thanks for that!